# Firebase authentication via Rest

Tags: firebase-authentication

When coding a c# windows app using the Rest API for firebase is it at all possible to use Firebases facebook authentication ? or are we limited to using only the Custom authentication approach.

Answer (score 1):

When calling the REST API, you are responsible for passing a valid JSON Web Token in the `auth` parameter. It has no built-in authentication methods.

You can either get a token from one the supported Identity Providers or you can mint one yourself.

Comment: so for facebook for instance I would just do my authentication in app using the conventional facebook mechanism (independently of firebase) and then I pass the token provided from facebook in my 'custom' authentication call to firebase. and thanks for answering & helping

Comment: Not really. Facebook would only give you an OAuth token. You'd still need to mint a JWT with that. We have libraries to help with that, including one for C#: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html So you take the information that you want in the token, put it in JSON and sign it into a JWT with that library. Then you pass the resulting token in the `auth` parameter.

Comment: I think I need to understand the way it works a lot more. Are there any examples for that kind of thing. I'm wanting to try to use firebase for as much of our online db type functionality as I can.  But I feel that having a firm grasp of the security is going to be key to that.