# How to authenticate in ruby via REST api

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to authenticate with ruby to firebase as Service Account.
So what I did so far, is using Google auth lib as I always did (in other google services):

```
require 'googleauth'
scopes =  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database"]
tt = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes).fetch_access_token
```

I get the tt["access_token"] and then I do something like

`curl -X POST -d '{"user_id" : "jack", "text" : "Ahoy!"}' 'https://project-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/message_list.json?access_token=ya29.CjHzAsjcGEQsSppI9AKCV9g4Uen7qlREI3N_nCGDsWkLh6ZSCg5JmNYzIU8NuV6PAq7h'`

Like they say in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth#section-get

and I get:
Permission denied (that is because in our DB Rules we said auth != null.
So I went ahead and called `?auth=ya29.CjHzAsjcGEQsSppI9AKCV9g4Uen7qlREI3N_nCGDsWkLh6ZSCg5JmNYzIU8NuV6PAq7h`

And I got:

```
"{\n  \"error\" : \"Could not parse auth token.\"\n}\n"
```

How am I supposed to authenticate to Firebase WITHOUT nodejs... just a simple REST???

Please assist!

Thanks!

Comment: The access token you get back from Google is not a valid token for Firebase. To exchange it, you will indeed require a trusted process (e.g. a server) to mint a JWT. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247677/firebase-authentication-via-rest

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen did that, and it said kid header is not in the token... – Himberjack 13 mins ago

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fully baked example, assuming you have an access token as described above:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'json'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXX'
DATABASE_NAME = 'YYY'

path = '/example'
auth_variable = {uid: 'ruby-admin'}
payload = {my: 'data'}

uri = URI("https://#{DATABASE_NAME}.firebaseio.com#{path}.json?auth_variable_override=#{CGI::escape auth_variable.to_json}")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')

req.body = payload.to_json
req['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{ACCESS_TOKEN}"

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

res = http.request(req)

puts res.body
```

You can edit `auth_variable` to change the `auth` variable available in security rules, and `payload` is obviously your data you want to post.