# Authenticating Firebase user in .NET application

Tags: asp.net, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a .NET application that asks a user to login with email and password. I'd like to be able to authenticate a Firebase user with .NET. Is this possible? In JavaScript it's easy to do through their SDK, but Firebase doesn't have a .NET SDK.

So then I thought maybe I could do it over the Firebase RESTful API. I did some research and I can't find a way to authenticate a user over the API. I know that you can authenticate a service account with the API, but how do you authenticate a user with email and password?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247677/firebase-authentication-via-rest

Comment: I'm asking about email/password. Not Facebook.

Comment: And yet the answer linked still answers your question thoroughly and accurately.